# Move iframe in front of popup window

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

please look at w ww.gcprive.com/happenings

I am trying to move the iframe that loads when you click on the "Sign-up" button to come in front of the popup window.

Any ideas where the fix might be?

Answer (score 1):

i think css is the simplest way to do it.

```
popup#first{
z-index:900;
}
popup#onerfirst{
z-index:901;
}
```

else you can actualy remove the old popup on signup click.

```
$('#first').remove();
```

or you can use `.fadeOut()`; instead of `.remove();` in case you need popup to be visible again if user does not create acc/login

Comment: thanks for this but unfortunately i am not good with editing javascript or jquery or whatever this is! I will try and go out the CSS route but i don't think there is a unique id for each popup.. ?

Comment: i think the coder used style='somethink' search in code for z-index. look for the background div. i think z-index is 10000 or 10001. use a higher number for the second popup. [higher than first one too]